# Simple Python server program to receive an image via http POST from Postman?

Tags: python, http

Does anybody know of an example Python script to receive an image sent via http POST from Postman?  I'd like to write a simple Python server script that could receive an image sent like this:

[image]

I'm 100% flexible on how the image is sent from Postman, for example I could use "form-data", then specify key/value/file, or use "binary".  Either way I'm looking for the Python server script to receive the file and either save it (to the same location as the Python server script, or a different location, does not really matter) or display it, either way to prove out that the server did receive the image.

Unfortunately all the Python server examples I can find send stuff rather than receive.  Can anybody provide some assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example that uses the built in BaseHTTPServer package for receiving GET/POST requests in python: http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=1658

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that does not work on Windows b/c of the line with the "os.fork()"